# Export email messages with attachments from Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

The constraints for this requirement are as follows:

- For legislative and/or governance purposes, the organization I am doing this for needs a way to extract email messages (with attachments) from a cloud instance of Dynamics, given a start date and end date;
- What's important is that the *content* be made available, not necessarily in a conventient format ("convenient" here I am suggesting is something like a neat MIME-encoded/RFC-822 formatted file, or even proprietary MS `.msg` format).  So, for instance, simply dumping the email body as a file, and the associated attachments as other files, grouped together in a folder somewhere is *good enough*;
- The solution needs to be as simple as possible, and should have *no technical support needs*;
- Here's the kicker: as much as this solution will necessitate a *custom* implementation (that is, *code*), we cannot employ anything outside the constraints of what we currently have in our Azure tenancy, that being: Dynamics 365 with the option of uploading custom plugins and/or custom workflow tasks *or* currently paid-for PaaS facilities, notably **Flow**.  This eliminates the option of having a console-based application, or even a web app.

I am aware of the fact that one can use Dynamics Advanced Find to export email data (even the body of the email sans attachments) into an Excel file.  We do need the email attachments, however.

What is a good way of implementing the above solution?

Comment: I think SSIS and KingswaySoft would be a good approach. I believe KingswaySoft now has a module for Attachments

Comment: @jasonscript the problem is that SSIS and/or KingswaySoft doesn't meet the criterion: "... cannot employ anything outside the constraints of what we currently have in our Azure tenancy ... ".

Comment: You can now deploy SSIS packages in Azure Data Factory, would this help with the constraints?

Comment: @KingswaySoft not really since we would have to purchase a KingswaySoft license :)